# Why would sendmsg() return EINVAL when passing SCM_CREDENTIALS as an ancillary message?

Tags: c, unix-socket

The sshtosnmp tool in net-snmp connects to a unix domain socket, and then attempts to send the uid, gid and pid over the unix domain socket to snmpd.

During this process, on RHEL9, the sendmsg() call returns EINVAL.

Can anyone confirm why EINVAL is being returned in this case?

strace reveals the following:

```
socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0)         = 3
setsockopt(3, SOL_SOCKET, SO_PASSCRED, [1], 4) = 0
connect(3, {sa_family=AF_UNIX, sun_path="/var/lib/net-snmp/sshdomainsocket"}, 110) = 0
getuid()                                = 0
getgid()                                = 0
getpid()                                = 12176
sendmsg(3, {msg_name=NULL, msg_namelen=0, msg_iov=[{iov_base="\1", iov_len=1}], msg_iovlen=1, msg_control=[{cmsg_len=32, cmsg_level=SOL_SOCKET, cmsg_type=SCM_CREDENTIALS, cmsg_data={pid=12176, uid=0, gid=0}}], msg_controllen=32, msg_flags=0}, MSG_DONTWAIT|MSG_NOSIGNAL) = -1 EINVAL (Invalid argument)
```

The man page for sendmsg describes EINVAL as follows:

```
       EINVAL Invalid argument passed.
```

Given the parameters passed to sendmsg above, what argument is invalid?